# Git - Commit and push local changes without losing file diffs?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, version-control, ide

I'm in `VSCode` and just made a ton of changes on my branch. I have a rough draft that would be a shame to lose due to to not backing up online. So naturally it would be smart to `git add .` my changes, then `git push origin myBranch` to create a remote backup.

But doing so will remove all my file diffs that `Visual Studio Code`'s interface shows me in the sidebar (see picture below). Is there a way I can push to a remote branch but still keep the changes unstaged (or bring them back to unstaged), or any way to at least keep those diff files so I can still continue work on my local and easily be able to see everywhere that I touched?

[image: 7 files changed, clicking here will show all my diffs]

Comment: and how do you want to make further commits on this branch, you only want the badge number to reflect the changed files compared to `master/main` branch

Comment: This is easy to do in *command line* Git: just make a commit (in the usual way) and send the commit to the server in the usual way (`git push`), then use `git reset --mixed` or `git reset --soft` (whichever you prefer) to "un-make" the commit locally. Note that you'll then need to `git push --force-with-lease` later to tell the *other* repository to discard the new commit. Alternatively, you can `git push HEAD:newbranch` to have the other repository save the commit under a different *branch name*, so that you can tell the other repository to discard that branch name later.

Comment: Whether there's some way to do this within VSCode, or make VSCode see what you're doing, I have no idea, though. (I also see I've repeated [j6t's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72150532/1256452).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make a commit and push it to make the remote backup.

Then you discard the commit locally with

```
git reset HEAD~
```

This points your branch to the previous commit and leaves all changes in the files so that you can see the diffs.

Be aware that you will have to force-push your branch later on when you have finished your local commits. That may or may not be a problem depending on how your remote repository is set up.

Answer (score 0):

*what will you push if you don't have any changes?*

simple solution will be . keep a copy all the files that you have made changes, then undo changes.

*later you can refer to the changes from copied files*

Answer (score 0):

save your work by using `git stash`. after pushing committed changes then you can call uncommitted changes as `git stash pop`. see the documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Comment: Using `git stash` makes commits, but the commits are on *no* branch, and cannot be synchronized to the server (not yet anyway, there's a project for Git 2.37 or some such to do this). The OP wants the server to contain the new commits, so this isn't going to accomplish the goal.